# Flutter Gridview under NestedScrollView TabBar Not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

Here is my structure:-

```
new NestedScrollView(
    headerSliverBuilder(
      SliverAppBar(..)
    )
    TabBarView(
      1> GridView.builder()
      2> Normal Text
    )
```

While I scroll my grid view tab bar won't collapse..but Normal text will work perfectly...

[image: this is dashboard code]
[image: this is my grid view]

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: I attached code picture....

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by removing scaffold widget in all tabbar view class... not use Scaffold when u use NestedScrollView for tabview.Thank You

Answer (score -2):

adding up to sakil's answer. instead of using scaffold, you can use Material to keep the "theme". Then the nested scrolling will work fine.